# Display Clock with Angular 6 and RxJs 6

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

How do I display a clock using rxjs 6 using Angular 6. The below code worked for angular 5. But now I am getting an error saying that interval is not of type Observable.

```
@Injectable()
export class MailService {

  private clock: Observable<Date>;


  constructor(private http : HttpClient) { 
    this.clock = Observable.interval(1000).map(tick => new Date()).share();
  }

  getClock(): Observable<Date> {
    return this.clock;
  }

}
```

Comment: You need to use the rxjs's new one: import { interval } from 'rxjs';

interval(1000).map(tick => new Date()).share();

Comment: For that I get an error saying map is not a function of interval

Comment: What about using interval(1000).subscribe(x => // do something) ?

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend some minor improvements to the given answers of [Sachila](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51442128/5726621) and [codeepic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51442171/5726621) for these issues:

1. The `interval()` operator emits its first value after the first
   period has past (see [docs](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-interval))
2. With `share()` a subsequent subscription could miss the last tick and has to wait 1s until the next value arrives. This could lead to a delayed display response.

Solution:

1. Using `timer(0, 1000)`: "Its like interval, but you can specify when the emissions should start." (see [docs](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-timer))
2. Using `shareReplay(1)`, where `1` indicates the number of previously emitted values that are emitted on a new subscription

Code (Angular 6 with RxJS 6):

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";

import { Observable, timer } from "rxjs";
import { map, shareReplay } from "rxjs/operators";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root"
})
export class ClockService {
  private _time$: Observable<Date> = timer(0, 1000).pipe(
    map(tick => new Date()),
    shareReplay(1)
  );

  get time() {
    return this._time$;
  }

  constructor() {}
}
```

To access the time:

```
import { ClockService } from "PATH/clock.service";

constructor(private _clockService: ClockService) {
   this._clockService.time.subscribe((now: Date) =>
     console.log("time:", now.toISOString())
   );
}
```

Comment: how do i get the time from your function than?

Answer (score 4):

from rxjs `6+` you have to use the `interval` operator.
if you are using operators use the `pipe` operators

```
import { interval } from 'rxjs';  
import { map, share } from 'rxjs/operators';

this.clock = interval(1000).pipe(  
    map(tick => new Date()),
    share()
)
```

Comment: getting the error 
"Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Observable<number>'."

Answer (score 2):

With RxJS 6 there were few changes. You import the functions differently and you chain them inside `pipe()` function. Few of the methods have been renamed too.
The code below will work with RxJS v6.

```
import {interval, Observable} from 'rxjs';
import {map, share} from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable()
export class MailService {

  private clock: Observable<Date>;

  constructor(private http : HttpClient) { 
    this.clock = interval(1000)
        .pipe(
            map(tick => new Date()),
            share()
        );
  }

  getClock(): Observable<Date> {
    return this.clock;
  }
}
```